# Joomla and legacy CodeIgniter website - use Joomla wrapper?

Tags: codeigniter, joomla, legacy

I am in the process of converting a CodeIgniter website to Joomla.  Most of the website is static data and should move over pretty well.  Though, there are a few places that we have a couple of workflows, views from data sources, etc.  Thinking of keeping existing CI pages for these and integrate into Joomla via it's Wrapper iframe control (for now).

Is this a good way to go (for the short term)?

I am new new at Joomla, so later on for full integration, would I create Joomla components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing specifically what the content is or what it looks like, it is hard to say how you would integrate it later. However, speaking in very general terms, there is a good possibility that you could port the content over without having to write custom extensions by using any number of [CCK components](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction). I would take a look at those solutions to see if you can avoid using iframes if at all possible.